# matlab indexing and manipulation

Tags: matlab, indexing

i need to access to particular elements in matrix in MATLAB. If I have matrix:

```
A = [1 1 2 1 1;
 1 2 2 2 1;
 1 2 2 2 1;
 1 1 2 1 1];
```

How can i manipulate with elements with value 2 or create a new matrix with them?

Comment: What do you mean "create a new matrix with them"?  What result are you aiming for?

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
index = find(A == 2)
```

it will return the index where you can find those values.

also you can do:

```
mappedIndex = A == 2
```

this will return the following for your matrix

```
A = [0 0 1 0 0;
 0 1 1 1 0;
 0 1 1 1 0;
 0 0 1 0 0];
```

Then it deppends of what you want to do.